# Passing object from javascript to PHP via AJAX, undefined variables in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm building a registration form modal and on button click, javascript will send an ajax request to the page `regajax.php` with the form content. My code is below, at the moment I'm only troubleshooting with `regajax.php` although the error_log still says that the variables are undefined.

Essentially, I want to send `obj` to `regajax.php` to check for errors and insert into my database on successful submission. (Before closing the modal, and without refreshing the page).

I've researched through countless stackoverflow posts and internet sources also to find an answer to my problem. Many have suggested using `JSON.stringify()`, which i'm currently trying to work with.

Note: In my source, the ajax script is below the form, in `<body>`.

```js
$("#regButton").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var obj = {
    fname: $('#fname').val(),
    lname: $('#lname').val(),
    email: $('#email').val(),
    pass: $('#password').val(),
    mobile: $('#mobile').val(),
    street: $('#street').val(),
    city: $('#city').val(),
    post: $('#post').val(),
    state: $('#state').val(),
    country: $('#country').val()
  }
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'regajax.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    success: function(response) {
      document.getElementById('error') = response;
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <div>
    <div class="error"></div>
    <div class="modal-form-left">
      <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" required><br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname" required><br>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" onKeyUp="checkEmail();" required value=""><br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass" id="password" onKeyUp='checkPass();' required pattern="(?=^.{6,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$"><br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="confirm_password" onKeyUp="checkPass();" required pattern="(?=^.{6,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$"><br>
      <input type="submit" id="regButton" value="Register">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-form-right">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" id="mobile" required><br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Street" id="street" required><br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="City" id="city" required><br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Post Code" id="post" name="post" required><input type="text" placeholder="State" name="state" id="state" required><br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Country" id="country" required><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
<?php
    $fname = $_POST["fname"];
    error_log($fname, 3, "./error_log");
?>
```

Comment: Just set object as data ,,,, `data: obj,`. No need to stringify. jQuery will form encode the object

Comment: Undefined index: fname is output in the error_log

Comment: Give all your form elements names, then just use $( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = $( this ).serialize();
});

Comment: Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network. See what is actually sent. Also do a dump of $_POST and see what is returned in response body in network tab

Comment: The data being sent look's fine, although it's in html. the output of $_POST is `array(0) {}`

Comment: i removed `dataType: 'json'`  and it works now. Thanks for the help :)